# Can C# decide what variable to assign a value to?

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement, types

Is there a way to write code so that when a user gives input, either a string or a number, that the program will choose the most appropriate of the available variables that have been declared?

Pseudocode example:

```
static void Main()
{
    int A;
    string B;

    Console.Write("enter something: ");

    if (user enters a number)
        A = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    else
        B = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You can decide. C# cannot decide.

Comment: What if it is a decimal or a GUID?

Answer (score 3):

Simply said, since `Console.ReadLine` is the way to receive user input, and since it always returns a `string`, no matter what: No, you have to parse the string for being a number yourself, and in turn assign it to the most fitting variable yourself.

You can do that with `int.TryParse`, which returns `true` if the given string could be parsed into a (integral) number, assigned to the second `out` parameter in the same line:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("enter something: ");
    string B = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(B, out int A))
        Console.WriteLine($"Yay, user entered number {A}.");
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"Nay, user entered a boring string {B}.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let `int.TryParse()` decide:

```
int A;
string B;

string userinput = Console.ReadLine();

// if parsing to int fails, assign to B
if (!int.TryParse(userinput, out A)
{
    B = userinput;
}
```